# Multiplying Across Tables Peoplesoft/Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, peoplesoft

I am trying to write a SQL for Peoplesoft that has the number of times tables (RECNAME) were used in queries by a user over a certain period of time.

From PSQRYRECORD I can retrieve QRYNAME & RECNAME (QRYNAME can have multiple RECNAME)

From PSQRYSTATS I can retrieve QRYNAME & EXECCOUNT (QRYNAME has only 1 EXECCOUNT), filtering by OPRID & LASTEXECDTTM.

But this is giving me too high amounts:

```
select A.RECNAME, Sum(B.EXECCOUNT) from FMSADM.PSQRYRECORD A, FMSADM.PSQRYSTATS B
WHERE A.QRYNAME = B.QRYNAME
AND  A.OPRID = 'JDOE'
AND B.LASTEXECDTTM BETWEEN to_date('01-JAN-16 00:00:00','DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('27-FEB-17 23:50:00','DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY A.RECNAME
ORDER BY Sum(B.EXECCOUNT) DESC
```

I think I need to count RECNAME then multiply by EXECCOUNT but can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that PSQRYRECORD may have the same OPRID,QRYNAME,RECNAME combo in more than one row.  When it does then your execcount is multiplied for that query.  You need to get the distinct OPRID,QRYNAME,RECNAME from PSQRYRECORD and then join this to PSQRYSTATS

```
WITH QRYREC AS (
    SELECT OPRID, QRYNAME, RECNAME
    FROM PSQRYRECORD
    GROUP BY OPRID, QRYNAME, RECNAME
)
SELECT QRYREC.RECNAME, SUM(QS.EXECCOUNT)
FROM QRYREC
JOIN PSQRYSTATS QS ON QS.QRYNAME = QRYREC.QRYNAME
WHERE
QRYREC.OPRID = 'JDOE'
AND QS.LASTEXECDTTM BETWEEN to_date('01-JAN-16 00:00:00','DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date('27-FEB-17 23:50:00','DD-Mon-YY HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY QRYREC.RECNAME
ORDER BY SUM(QS.EXECCOUNT) DESC
```